# hadoop reducer local variable always initialize

Tags: java, variables, hadoop, local

I have a class variable in the Reducer class:

```
public static class ReduceClass extends 
                             Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    int N = 0;

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
                                     throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable value : values) {
            sum += value.get();
        }

        if (key.equals(something)) 
        {
            N += sum;
        } 

        else 
        {
            if(N > 0) context.write(key, new IntWritable(N));
            else    //write something else
        }
    }
}
```

However, even thought the 'key.equals(something)' satisfies (it does at least once, definitely), N is always 0 between reduce function calls.

Interesting thing is, that if I add 'N++' to the beginning of the function, the value of N does increment between reduce calls - but 'N+=sum' doesn't affect at all! Like it never executes.

What am I doing wrong? I just need N to keep it's value between reduce calls. Per-Reducer, of course.

TIA.

Comment: Can you increment `N` outside the if statement?  I know you say that it happens at least once, but that contradicts the results you're seeing. Reduce tasks usually maintain state throughout the lifetime of the attempt.

Comment: Are you sure "something" is of type Text with same contents as key? Can you include a print statement in if loop and check if you are entering loop?

Comment: You guys were right, it wasn't entering the 'if' block... Fixed the bug and now it works!